# Google sheets---->BigQuery migration

Tags: google-bigquery

I have to do a data migration from google sheets to bigquery.

What is the most optimal way to do it? any advice?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Check out Seekwell.io.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a table which uses Google Sheet as a datasource.
[image]
https://towardsdatascience.com/connect-bigquery-to-google-sheets-e3c4f1377659

Answer (score 1):

You can migrate data from `Google Sheets` to `BigQuery` by using an `Add-ons` in your `Google Sheets`. The name of add-ons is `BigQuery Uploader for Sheets`.

[image]

- In `Google Sheets`, go to `Add-ons` > `Get add-ons` in the menu and search `BigQuery Uploader for Sheets`

[image]

- After the installation, you will see the add-ons.

[image]

- You can set up your upload definitions.

[image]

- You can run manual upload or use schedule uploads.

[image]

- If successful, you will see the "Success" message.

[image]

- You can see that data in `Google Sheets` have been migrated successfully to `BigQuery`.

[image]

[image]

[image]